# Comment-based Help for a Function also includes alias

Tags: powershell, comments, alias

After writing the annotations for the function, I hope to display the content, **including Alias** using the `Get-Help` command. Unfortunately, I did not find an example of in the official documentation<sup>[Comment-based Help for a Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-7.3#comment-based-help-for-a-function)</sup>.

my.psm1

```
function MyFuncDefault() {
    echo "default"
}
Set-Alias myD MyFuncDefault


<#
.SYNOPSIS
    ...
.DESCRIPTION
    desc
.LINK
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-7.3#comment-based-help-for-a-function
#>
function MyFunc() {
    echo "default"
}
Set-Alias myF MyFunc
```

my.psd1

```
@{
ModuleVersion = '1.0'
NestedModules = @(
    'my.psm1'
)
FunctionsToExport = @(
    'MyFuncDefault',
    'MyFunc'
)
CmdletsToExport = @()
VariablesToExport = '*'
AliasesToExport = @(
    'MyD',
    'MyF'
)
PrivateData = @{
    PSData = @{
    }
}
}
```

If I don’t write function annotations, the **default** behavior is to generate an `Alias` item for me, but when I write, the Alias is gone. I don't know why?

Input: Default

```
Get-Help MyFuncDefault -Full
```

output

```yaml
NAME
    MyFuncDefault
SYNTAX
    MyFuncDefault
PARAMETERS
    None
INPUTS
    None
OUTPUTS
    System.Object
ALIASES #  When I don’t write function comments, the default behavior is to generate an Alias item automatically
    myD
REMARKS
    None
```

input: customize

```
Get-Help MyFunc -Full
```

output:

```
NAME
    MyFunc
SYNOPSIS
    ...
SYNTAX
    MyFunc [<CommonParameters>]
DESCRIPTION
    desc
PARAMETERS
    <CommonParameters>
        This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug,
        ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable,
        OutBuffer, PipelineVariable, and OutVariable. For more information, see
        about_CommonParameters (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216).
INPUTS
OUTPUTS
RELATED LINKS
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=p
    owershell-7.3#comment-based-help-for-a-function
```

`Alias` is missing

---

[comment-based-help-for-a-function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-7.3#forwardhelpcategory)

I try to add `.FORWARDHELPCATEGORY Alias` still do not work.

---

I know I can find the alias by the full command name, like

```
Get-Alias -Definition MyFunc
```

output:

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           myF -> MyFunc                                      1.0        user
```

But I **prefer** getting it from the `Get-Help` command to know the description, examples, alias, and more.

Comment: Looks like a bug in `Get-Help` cmdlet. Tried to find its source code, without success…